# UIView.transition animation causing view to become nil

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Goal of code is that on each tap of a view containing 2 UIImageview, to have the bottom image go on top of the to image, and so on each time I tap.

I have a view container with 2 UIImageview on top of each other:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imagesContainer: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageZero: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageOne: UIImageView!
```

I add a tap gesture in ViewDidLoad:

```
 let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapImagesContainer(_:)))
 self.imagesContainer.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer
```

Also a top level variable, to control which image to bring on top, and which to push down:

```
      var imageOnTopIsImageZero = true
```

so that when I tap on the container, the under image comes on top.
While developing I implemented a transition without animation:

```
@objc func didTapImagesContainer(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let imageToBringOnTop: UIImageView? = imageOnTopIsImageZero ? self.imageOne : self.imageZero
    let ImagetoBringDown: UIImageView? = imageOnTopIsImageZero ? self.imageZero : self.imageOne
    
    imageToBringOnTop?.layer.zPosition = 1.0
    ImagetoBringDown?.layer.zPosition = 0.0
    self.imageOnTopIsImageZero.toggle()
}
```

This works fine. Now I tried to implement the same transition with animation:

```
@objc func didTapImagesContainer(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let imageToBringOnTop: UIImageView? = imageOnTopIsImageZero ? self.imageOne : self.imageZero
    let ImagetoBringDown: UIImageView? = imageOnTopIsImageZero ? self.imageZero : self.imageOne
    
    UIView.transition(from: ImagetoBringDown!, to: imageToBringOnTop!, duration: 1.0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, completion: nil)
    self.imageOnTopIsImageZero.toggle()
}
```

The first time I tap on the image, the transition happens correctly, underimage is cross disolved into the on top image.
But on the second tap, imageToBringOnTop is nil!

I really don't understand why the animation has an effect on the view content. What is the cause, and how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs say:
fromView
The starting view for the transition. By default, this view is removed from its superview as part of the transition.

Detail:
The idea of a transition animation is that you're changing the view hierarchy by replacing one view with another in an animated way. If you are not doing such a 'transition', you can use other (non-transition) animation API like animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:

Or there is support for keeping two views in the hierarchy, one shown, one hidden, using the transition animation API, if you include UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews in the option set:

```
UIView.transition(from: ImagetoBringDown!, to: imageToBringOnTop!,
   duration: 1.0,
   options: [.transitionCrossDissolve, .showHideTransitionViews],
   completion: nil)
```

So "showHideTransitionViews" means 'show/hide the from/to instead of add/remove'

Comment: any way to prevent that?

Comment: Consider using animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:

Comment: Actually you can just include UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews in the options, if you want to use your transition animation.

Comment: this is exactly it. If you want to take credit for answer you can post this: UIView.transition(from: ImagetoBringDown!, to: imageToBringOnTop!, duration: 1.0, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve, .showHideTransitionViews], completion: nil)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting the z positions, `transition` actually removes the `from` view from the view hierarchy, and adds the `to` view to the view hierarchy ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622562-transition)):

> #### Parameters
>
> `fromView`
>
> The starting view for the transition. By default, this view is
> **removed from its superview** as part of the transition.
>
> `toView` The ending view for the transition. By default, this view is
> **added to the superview of fromView** as part of the transition.

Also note that since your VC is holding a *weak* reference to the images, their superviews are the only objects holding a strong reference to them. Once one of them is removed from its superview, your VC's weak reference becomes nil.

To fix this, simply use strong references, remove the word `weak`:

```
@IBOutlet var imageZero: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var imageOne: UIImageView!
```